# Get thumbnail of the newest picasa picture using the Google Data Api

Tags: picasa, google-data-api

What i want to do is simple, once the user logged in i want to retrieve the newest picture he uploaded to picasa to show as a preview for a gallery.

I previously had a solution querying for:

> https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=photo&max-results=1&thumbsize=320&fields=entry(media:group(media:thumbnail))

However it no longer works, I believe this is because this way is now deprecated.

Basically using partial response as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#PartialResponse) I want to get an xml response that i can parse. (I got the parsing also figured out).

The problem is that i can't seem to find the "right" combination of **field** values that will give me just 1 picture that **IS NOT** the user icon. Using the old way described above I am not even getting a single one.

Answer (score 1):

You may try "Listing photos recently uploaded":

Form the documentation:

> It is also possible to retrieve the photos associated with a user, but without specifying any particular album. The following request retrieves the last 10 photos uploaded by userID:

```
GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/userID?kind=photo&max-results=10
```

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Photos